# How to delete duplicated fields from two different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

Imagine that you have two tables.

Table bar:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Table foo:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name_alternative | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And you want to remove the rows from table `bar` that have the same `name` value as the field `name_alternative` from table `foo`

I could use the following query:

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE name IN (SELECT name_alternative FROM bar);
```

But this takes a very long time to execute having a large amount of records in both tables.

So I was wondering if there is a better alternative to this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way that would work, and I think it would be more efficient:

```
DELETE FROM bar
    USING foo, bar
    WHERE name_alternative = name
```

Here is a [working SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea1db/1).

[See the documentation for delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).

Comment: This generates the following error message: ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'bar' in MULTI DELETE

Comment: I think this is the correct answer: `DELETE FROM bar USING foo, bar WHERE name_alternative = name;` could you correct it in order to mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: @rfc1484, sorry for the typo.  It is corrected now and has a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Besides @dan1{4} answer, my guess is that it takes a long time because there is no index on `bar(name)`.

You don't need an index covering the whole 255 chars, depending on your strings, ie if the first characters are different on a lot of rows, create an index on a few characters

```
CREATE INDEX indexname ON bar(name(8))
```

`8` is a suggested value that you may want to refine. The index will help mysql to locate each *bar* row that matches a *foo.namealternative*

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from bar
using (
    select foo.name_alternative
    from 
        bar
        inner join
        foo on bar.name = foo.name_alternative
) s
where bar.name = s.name_alternative
```